# Finding the solution of the nonhomogenous linar system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

I have the system $$\dot{x_1}=x_1+2x_2-6, \enspace \enspace x_1(0)=1 \\ \dot{x_2}=6x_1-3x_2+24 \enspace\enspace x_2(0)=-1$$
and want to find the solution of this IVP. I wrote the system as $$\dot{x}=Ax+b(t)$$ where $$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 6 & -3 \end{matrix} \right) \text{ and }  b(t) = \left( \begin{matrix} -6 \\ 24 \end{matrix} \right). $$

I am studying from Perko's book and it says the following. If $e^{At}$ is any fundamental matrix solution of the system $\dot{x}=Ax$ then the solution of the nonhomogeneous linear system has the form $$ x(t)=e^{At}x_0 + e^{At} \int_{0}^{t} e^{-A\tau} b(\tau) d\tau. $$

To find $e^{At}$, I diagonalize $A$ by finding its eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and then corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$. So that I construct the matrix $P$ which has columns $v_1$ and $v_2$. Thus, I could be able to write $e^{At}=Pe^{Bt}P^{-1}$ where $B=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. However, I think that there must be some easier way to find the solution as $b(t)$ does not depend on $t$ actually.

To sum up,

1. How can I find the solution of these type of systems where the nonhomogeneous part does not depend on the parameter?
2. How can I convert the system to a (probably) second order differential equation?

Comment: No matter what you are doing, your solution will involve calculating $v_1$ and $v_2$

Comment: I see, but I wonder is there any shortcut if the vector $b(t)$ does not depend on the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dot{x_1}=x_1+2x_2-6, \enspace \enspace x_1(0)=1 \\ \dot{x_2}=6x_1-3x_2+24 \enspace\enspace x_2(0)=-1$$
Substract both differential equations:
$${x'_1}-x'_2=-5x_1+5x_2-30$$
$$({x_1}-x_2)'=-5(x_1-x_2)-30$$
$$(({x_1}-x_2)e^{5t})'=-30e^{5t}$$
It's easy to integrate:
$$({x_1}-x_2)e^{5t}=-6e^{5t}+c_1$$
$${x_1}=x_2-6+c_1e^{-5t}$$
Note that since we have :
$$x_1(0)=1, x_2(0)=-1 \implies c_1=8$$
Substitute this in the second differential equation and solve to get $x_2$. Here substitute $x_1$:
$$\dot{x_2}=6\color {red}{x_1}-3x_2+24 $$
$$\dot{x_2}=6\color {red}{(x_2-6+8e^{-5t} )}-3x_2+24 $$
Then solve the equation, it's a first order DE:
$$\dot{x_2}-3x_2=48e^{-5t}-12 $$
$$({x_2}e^{-3t})'=48e^{-8t}-12e^{-3t} $$

---

*2. How can I convert the system to a (probably) second order differential equation?*

Just differentiate one of the two differential equation and substitute in the second one. Then you have a second order linear differential equation that you can easily solve.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I took the derivative of the first and obtained a second order DE in terms of $y$ by setting $y=x_1$. I guess by using the initial condition for $x_1$ I obtain the solution $x_1(t)$. Then, when do I use the second initial condition $x_2(0)$ to get the $x_2(t)$? After plugging the solution of $x_1(t)$ in one of the equations?

Comment: You're very welcome @Ninja

Comment: excuse me but I think I miss some point. After the integration in your answer I found $x_1e^{5t}=x_2e^{5t}+8$. Then how I can explicitly write $x_1$ and $x_2$ separately? I also asked one more question in my comment above so I would appreciate if you could answer it too

Comment: Substitute in one of the differential equation and solve it'"s then a first order @Ninja

Comment: I added some lines for the integration....@Ninja